# Shouldn't the numerator of the second term in the summation in the last result be $-3\alpha x_{j0}(x_{k}-x_{k0})$?

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

[image]

Shouldn't the numerator of the second term in the summation in the last result be $-3\alpha x_{j0}(x_{k}-x_{k0})$?